# Literature / Books on Linear Models, Generalized Linear Models and Linear Mixed Models

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, references, linear-model

As the title suggests, I'm looking for book recommendations on *Linear Models*, *Generalized Linear Models* and *Linear Mixed Models*.

The book should give a good overview on the intuition behind approaches, which problems they enable to solve, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not home now and can't check my books, but I believe Gelman and Hill *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel Models* covers all of these.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the book seems very well structured.